# Using Extjs 4 RestProxy with Delphi XE2 server

Tags: rest, delphi, extjs4

I'm trying to use the 'rest' proxy with extjs to connect to my delphi xe2 rest server.

This does a request and works when I use jsonp

```js
proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    api: {
        create: {url:"http://10.0.29.64:8080/datasnap/rest/tsmbank/client", method:"PUT"},
        read: "http://10.0.29.64:8080/datasnap/rest/tsmbank/client",
        update: {url:"http://10.0.29.64:8080/datasnap/rest/tsmbank/client", method:"POST"},
        destroy: {url:"http://10.0.29.64:8080/datasnap/rest/tsmbank/Client", method:"DELETE"}
    },

    callbackKey: 'theCallbackFunction',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'allclients',
        totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    },
    writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
         //type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true
    })
}
```

But if I try to use the Restproxy type it sends an "OPTIONS" method

```js
proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    url: "http://10.0.29.64:8080/datasnap/rest/tsmbank/client",
    callbackKey: 'theCallbackFunction',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'allclients',
        totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    },
    writer: new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
        //type: 'json',
        writeAllFields:true
    })
}
```

Or I guess the other quetions is how to handle the "OPTIONS" request method with a delphi rest server?

Comment: Is the page you are making the request from served from the exactly the same ip/port (10.0.29.64:8080)? I had the same problem until i realised the port does matter - Firefox (and possibly Chrome) will generate an OPTIONS method if it looks like a cross domain request.